# How do I get the exit code of a process, which runs through wine

Tags: bash, wine, exit

I'm trying to run a Windows executable via wine. When I first try to run it never runs, but when I attempt to do it again, the program runs.

I'd like to make a script to run the program, here's the the important part of the script:

```
EXECUTABLE=$(env XMODIFIERS="" wine hl.exe .nomaster -strechaspect)
$EXECUTABLE
echo "Exit Status = $?"
```

With this it never gives me the message "Exit Status 0", because, wine finishes successfully, but the "hl.exe" exits with an error because that didn't start in the first try, just the second try as i stated in the beginning.

I first thought something like this might do:

```
e=$?
if [ $e -ne 0 ]
then
  echo
  echo "Exit with Error"
  echo
fi
```

but it never shows me the message "Exit Status = 0".

Can someone help me with how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know about wine, but if `$EXECUTABLE` talks to stdout or stderr you could grep for an error or message which only appears upon failure. `$EXECUTABLE | grep "error"` when using a pipe, the variable `$?` has the exit value of the last program in the pipe. If you're interested in this solution, I can make it an answer.

Comment: The script that wraps WINE might have a bug in it. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=109668. There was one that was fixed back in 2001, perhaps that fix has some issues with certain edge cases.

Comment: Can you modify your `wine` command to run something like `hl.exe .nomaster -strechaspect & echo %errorlevel%`? Possibly writing the `errorlevel` to a file, to make it easier for the shell script to capture it? (You will almost surely need to quote or escape the `&` to prevent the shell from interpreting it.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok , i has solve with a workaround , because , it's not possible obtain the wine windows executable exit status code.

Ok i put the follow

```
EXECUTABLE=$(env XMODIFIERS="" wine hl.exe .nomaster -strechaspect)
$EXECUTABLE
HL1EXE=$(ps -A | grep hl.exe | awk '{print $4}')

if [ -z "$HL1EXE"]; then
       echo
       echo "Try to Launch again wait" 
       echo
       sleep 3
       EXECUTABLE=$(env XMODIFIERS="" wine hl.exe .nomaster -strechaspect)
       $EXECUTABLE
       HL1EXE=$(ps -A | grep hl.exe | awk '{print $4}')
       echo "Executable File : $HL1EXE"
fi
```

and ready , the game Start.